# Reference for the results of the paper "On a class of probability spaces" by David Blackwell

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Is there a modern book that summarizes the results from the paper "On a class of probability spaces" by David Blackwell (1956)?

https://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/math/ucb/text/math_s3_v2_article-01.pdf